# How to use a geolocation component that watches changes in geolocation?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, geolocation, react-hooks

I have a App component which is:

```
import Home from './screens/Home';
import * as React from 'react';

const App = () => {
  return <Home />;
};

export default App;
```

My home component looks like:

```
  export default class Home extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.heading}> Location Manager </Text>
          <CurrentLocation />
          <LocationList />
        </View>
        <ClearButton />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

I wrote a component that watches for location changes:
it looks like:

```
export const useGeolocation = (): [string, GeolocationData] => {
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [position, setPosition] = useState<GeolocationData>({
    latitude: 0,
    longitude: 0,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const watchId = Geolocation.watchPosition(
      (pos) => {
        setError('');
        setPosition({
          latitude: pos.coords.latitude,
          longitude: pos.coords.longitude,
        });
      },
      (e) => setError(e.message),
    );
    return () => Geolocation.clearWatch(watchId);
  }, []);

  return [error, position];
};
```

Now how do I use this component? where do I place this? I read it on a tutorial that it will unsubscribe when user is not using the app (backgrounded) or component will unmount? How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next try. Just import it and use :)

```js
import { useGeolocation } from './useGeolocation';
import Home from './screens/Home';
import * as React from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const geoLocation = useGeolocation();
  return <Home gl={geoLocation} />;
};

export default App;
```

Comment: But I am simply listening for location changes? why would I need a router?

Comment: Good question, maybe you really don't need router. Let me think some minutes.

Comment: Omg, when you ask about location you talk about geolocation?

Comment: Is it more correct question: How to use a geolocation component that watches changes in geolocation?

Comment: Oh now I get it! Thank you so much :)